# Displaying file contents issue using while loop

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
{ cat sample.txt; echo; } | while read -r -a A_Name; do
if [ ! -z "${A_Name[0]}" ]; then
echo " ${A_Name[0]%.isx} "
fi
done
```

I am trying to display contents of a text file (which includes .isx files) using while loop but when i try to eliminate extension with %, it doesnt work.

#### Output

`.isx` is appearing for first two values:

```
./test.sh
 abc.isx
 def.isx
 ghi
```

#### Input

`sample.txt` file:

```
abc.isx
def.isx
ghi.isx
```

Please, assist. Thank you.

Comment: Please add more details about your problem so we can answer your question

Comment: Does the file have DOS/Windows-style line endings?

Comment: No it doesn't have. infact its an empty file. just displaying the output without .isx. it worked fine with for loop but not with while loop..thank you

Answer (score 1):

why so complicated?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat sample.txt | while read line; do
    echo "${line%.isx}"
done
```

or with sed

```
sed "s/\.isx//" sample.txt >output.txt
```

or with sed and inplace replacement

```
sed -i "s/\.isx//" sample.txt
```